# Get length of .wav from sox output

Tags: audio, grep, pipe, wav, sox

I need to get the length of a .wav file.

Using:

```
sox output.wav -n stat
```

Gives:

```
Samples read:            449718
Length (seconds):     28.107375
Scaled by:         2147483647.0
Maximum amplitude:     0.999969
Minimum amplitude:    -0.999969
Midline amplitude:     0.000000
Mean    norm:          0.145530
Mean    amplitude:     0.000291
RMS     amplitude:     0.249847
Maximum delta:         1.316925
Minimum delta:         0.000000
Mean    delta:         0.033336
RMS     delta:         0.064767
Rough   frequency:          660
Volume adjustment:        1.000
```

How do I use grep or some other method to only output the value of the length in the second column, i.e. 28.107375?

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `stat` effect sends its output to `stderr`, use `2>&1` to redirect to `stdout`. Use `sed` to extract the relevant bits:

```
sox out.wav -n stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\)$#\1#p'
```

Comment: I've got no idea how you constructed this, but it works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: For what it's worth, using sox v14.0.0 on Windows, the $ (EOL) marker caused this answer to fail to give the result expected (instead of parsing to the end of line, it simply parses till it finds something which isn't a digit or period.

Comment: This is more reliable than `soxi`: this one involves traversing the audio file to _calculate_ the length whereas `soxi` simply reports what is in the header - regardless of accuracy

Answer (score 61):

There is a better way:

```
soxi -D out.wav
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns wrong duration, distinguish from `sox output.wav -n stat` method in my case.

Comment: I have never seen it to be wrong - can you distinguish in what situation this is incorrect?

Comment: I've cropped the audio with http://mp3cut.net/ and got the warn from sox: `WARN mp3-util: MAD lost sync` with wrong duration. On the other hand `sox output.wav -n stat` execution returns correct duration in error output thread (see my answer for explanation). Also windows explorer shows correct duration.

Comment: FWIW - I've used this method on linux and mac for years without any such issue - sounds windows specific.

Comment: I think the two differ in that soxi uses the header info, while sox looks at the body, too. SO if the header is wrong, the two give different outpu.

Comment: @RuprechtvonWaldenfels Interesting theory. Can anyone confirm this? I can't see anything on a quick glance at the man pages.

Comment: Why theory? Man directly states it [for `soxi` (`sox --info`)](https://linux.die.net/man/1/soxi): "Displays information from the header of a given audio file or files.", [for sox stat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sox): "Display time and frequency domain statistical information about the audio. Audio is passed unmodified through the SoX processing chain." You could read further how it statistics collected and calculated also.

Answer (score 14):

This can be done by using:

- `soxi -D input.mp3` the output will be the duration directly in seconds
- `soxi -d input.mp3` the output will be the duration with the following format hh:mm:ss.ss

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me (in Windows):

```
sox --i -D out.wav
```

Comment: Unfortunately it returns wrong duration, distinguish from `sox output.wav -n stat` method in my case.

Comment: stat returned  139.389388 and this returned 139.407007. For my purposes it's OK. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I just added an option for JSON output on the 'stat' and 'stats' effects. This should make getting info about an audiofile a little bit easier.

https://github.com/kylophone/SoxJSONStatStats

```
$ sox somefile.wav -n stat -json
```

Answer (score 2):

for ruby:

```
string = `sox --i -D file_wav 2>&1` 
string.strip.to_f
```

Answer (score 1):

There is my solution for C# (unfortunately `sox --i -D out.wav` returns wrong result in some cases):

```cs
public static double GetAudioDuration(string soxPath, string audioPath)
{
    double duration = 0;
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(soxPath,
        string.Format("\"{0}\" -n stat", audioPath));
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    var process = Process.Start(startInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();

    string str;
    using (var outputThread = process.StandardError)
        str = outputThread.ReadToEnd();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
        using (var outputThread = process.StandardOutput)
            str = outputThread.ReadToEnd();

    try
    {
        string[] lines = str.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        string lengthLine = lines.First(line => line.Contains("Length (seconds)"));
        duration = double.Parse(lengthLine.Split(':')[1]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

    return duration;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CentOS

> sox out.wav -e stat 2>&1 | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*([0-9.]*)$#\1#p'

Answer (score 0):

sox stat output to array and json encode

```
        $stats_raw = array();
        exec('sox file.wav -n stat 2>&1', $stats_raw);
        $stats = array();

        foreach($stats_raw as $stat) {
            $word = explode(':', $stat);
            $stats[] = array('name' => trim($word[0]), 'value' => trim($word[1]));
        } 
        echo json_encode($stats);
```