# How to get the duration of a file in milliseconds

Tags: shell, avconv

I am trying to get the duration of an audio file (.wav) in milliseconds.

I have seen some command lines using `ffmpeg`, but this library is deprecated (remplaced by `avconv`) on my Ubuntu version, and i didn't find anything on it.

I can get the duration by running `avconv -i <file>` but i am looking for the result in `milliseconds`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534372/get-length-of-wav-from-sox-output

Answer (score 0):

Wrote this as a small stand-alone `.sh`file:

```
file="$1"
info=$(sox $file -n stat 2>&1)
full_length=$(echo "$info" | sed -n 's#^Length (seconds):[^0-9]*\([0-9.]*\).*$#\1#p')
seconds=$(echo $full_length | cut -f1 -d.)

if [ -n "$seconds" ]; then
    milliseconds=$(echo $full_length | cut -f2 -d. | cut -c -3)

    result=$(($seconds * 1000))
    result=$(($result + $milliseconds))

    echo "$result"
    exit
fi

echo "0"
exit
```

Call it like

```
new-file.sh test.wav
```

To get a result like (duration in ms)

```
1337
```

(You can find the full code with all sources I used on [GitHub](https://github.com/blaues0cke/PiSleepTalk/blob/2a8adca1bda6f6ec2ef654aae9336281869c0434/bash/tool/length-of-audio-file-in-ms.sh))